# Issue Instantiating Block in Minecraft like Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate blocks like Minecraft with a Raycast. It works, but if I click a block with a different rotation to (0,0,0), my block spawn in the same position of the block that I clicked.

[Here is a video of what I mean](https://streamable.com/nwtx3y)

**My code:**

```
Vector3 SnappedPosition(Vector3 pointToSnap, Vector3 blockCenterPosition)
{
    Vector3 relativePosition = pointToSnap - blockCenterPosition;
    Debug.Log("pointToSnap ="+pointToSnap);
    Debug.Log("blockCenterPosition =" + blockCenterPosition);
    Debug.Log("relativePosition = pointToSnap - blockCenterPosition =" + relativePosition);
    if (relativePosition.x == 0.5) { Debug.Log("Vector.right"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.right; }
    if (relativePosition.x == -0.5){ Debug.Log("Vector.left"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.left; }
    if (relativePosition.y == 0.5) { Debug.Log("Vector.up"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.up; }
    if (relativePosition.y == -0.5) { Debug.Log("Vector.down"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.down; }
    if (relativePosition.z == 0.5) { Debug.Log("Vector.forwad"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.forward; }
    if (relativePosition.z == -0.5) { Debug.Log("Vector.back"); return blockCenterPosition + Vector3.back; }
    Debug.Log("Vector3.zero"); 
    return Vector3.zero;  // error (should not occur)
        
}
void Start()
{
    hand = dust;
    // to avoid collision with player camera during raycast
    playerMask = ~LayerMask.GetMask("Player"); // everything except the player mask
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))  // right click --> place block
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
        {
            Vector3 pointToSnap = hit.point;
            Vector3 blockCenterPosition = hit.collider.transform.localPosition;
            Vector3 instantiatePosition = SnappedPosition(pointToSnap, blockCenterPosition);
            Debug.Log("instatiatePosition = blockCenterPosition + Vector " + instantiatePosition);
            Instantiate(hand, instantiatePosition, Quaternion.identity);  
        }
    }
}
```

Debug:
Place 2 block.
No change rotation at runtime : Work

- pointToSnap = (0.0,-0.5,0.0)
- blockCenterPosition = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
- relativePosition = pointToSnap - blockCenterPosition = (0.0,0.5,0.0)
- Vector.up
- instatiatePosition = blockCenterPosition + Vector(Vector.up) =
  (0.0,1.0,0.0);

Debug:
Place 2 block.
Change rotation at runtime (90,0,0): Don't work

- pointToSnap = (0.2,-0.5,0.0)
- blockCenterPosition = (0.0,0.0,0.0)
- relativePosition = pointToSnap - blockCenterPosition = (0.2,0.5,0.0)
- Vector.zero(why if relativePosition.y is 0.5.The right answer is Vector.up) <--**ERROR** (look SnappedPosition function).
- instatiatePosition = blockCenterPosition + Vector(Vector.zero) =
  (0.0,0.0,0.0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** directly compare `float` values using `==`. Due to [floating point precision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) something like `5 * 0.2f / 10f` might be `0.99999999` or `1.0000000001` so a check for `== 1f` would **fail**!

Therefore you would always rather check if it lies within a certain **range** like e.g.

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a - b) <= threshold)
```

---

Unity provides [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) for approximately comparing two floats you should use instead.

> Compares two floating point values and returns true if they are similar.
>
> Floating point imprecision makes comparing floats using the equals operator inaccurate. For example, (1.0 == 10.0 / 10.0) might not return true every time. Approximately() compares two floats and returns true if they are within a small value (Epsilon) of each other.

So

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(a, b))
```

basically equals doing

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a - b) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
```

where [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) is

> The smallest value that a float can have different from zero.